# How to password protect multiple Excel 2007 files with multiple passwords using a Macro?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I'm new here so please let me know if my post is incorrect or anything like that.

I currently have a macro that splits out one excel file into multiple files and saves them separately. This step I have found an answer to and am quite happy with.

I need these files to be password protected so when I email them out to clients I feel that they are being transmitted securely. Is there a macro that I can write/use to accomplish this trick for me.

My excel file Tab 1 houses all of my data and currently splits out everything based on column A.

```
John Test1
John Test2
John Test3
Alex Test4
Alex Test5
Frank Test6
Frank Test7
```

The macro I use splits this into separates file for John/Alex/Frank that shows only their data with none of the other individuals data.

I also have tab 2 that houses all of the passwords:

```
John Pw1
Alex Pw2
Frank Pw3
```

I am looking for a way to have the passwords listed in tab 2 to be applied to the newly created documents during the process of my current macro.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated. Let me know if any of what I asked is unclear.

For reference I will quote the code I found from user mtone because this is the code I am currently using. This code has been very useful for me and I am extremely thankful to mtone for posting it. I don't believe I can send a private message to mtone but if I could I would thank him profusely!

```
    Public Sub SplitToFiles()

    ' MACRO SplitToFiles
    ' Last update: 2012-03-04
' Author: mtone
' Version 1.1
' Description:
' Loops through a specified column, and split each distinct values into a separate file by making a copy and deleting rows below and above
'
    ' Note: Values in the column should be unique or sorted.
'
' The following cells are ignored when delimiting sections:
' - blank cells, or containing spaces only
' - same value repeated
' - cells containing "total"
'
' Files are saved in a "Split" subfolder from the location of the source workbook, and named after the section name.

Dim osh As Worksheet ' Original sheet
Dim iRow As Long ' Cursors
Dim iCol As Long
Dim iFirstRow As Long ' Constant
Dim iTotalRows As Long ' Constant
Dim iStartRow As Long ' Section delimiters
Dim iStopRow As Long
Dim sSectionName As String ' Section name (and filename)
Dim rCell As Range ' current cell
Dim owb As Workbook ' Original workbook
Dim sFilePath As String ' Constant
Dim iCount As Integer ' # of documents created

iCol = Application.InputBox("Enter the column number used for splitting", "Select column", 2, , , , , 1)
iRow = Application.InputBox("Enter the starting row number (to skip header)", "Select row", 5, , , , , 1)
iFirstRow = iRow

Set osh = Application.ActiveSheet
Set owb = Application.ActiveWorkbook
iTotalRows = osh.UsedRange.Rows.Count
sFilePath = Application.ActiveWorkbook.Path

If Dir(sFilePath + "\Split", vbDirectory) = "" Then
MkDir sFilePath + "\Split"
End If

'Turn Off Screen Updating  Events
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Do
' Get cell at cursor
Set rCell = osh.Cells(iRow, iCol)
sCell = Replace(rCell.Text, " ", "")

If sCell = "" Or (rCell.Text = sSectionName And iStartRow <> 0) Or InStr(1, rCell.Text, "total", vbTextCompare) <> 0 Then
    ' Skip condition met
Else
    ' Found new section
    If iStartRow = 0 Then
        ' StartRow delimiter not set, meaning beginning a new section
        sSectionName = rCell.Text
        iStartRow = iRow
    Else
        ' StartRow delimiter set, meaning we reached the end of a section
        iStopRow = iRow - 1

        ' Pass variables to a separate sub to create and save the new worksheet
        CopySheet osh, iFirstRow, iStartRow, iStopRow, iTotalRows, sFilePath, sSectionName, owb.fileFormat
        iCount = iCount + 1

        ' Reset section delimiters
        iStartRow = 0
        iStopRow = 0

        ' Ready to continue loop
        iRow = iRow - 1
    End If
End If

' Continue until last row is reached
If iRow < iTotalRows Then
        iRow = iRow + 1
Else
    ' Finished. Save the last section
    iStopRow = iRow
    CopySheet osh, iFirstRow, iStartRow, iStopRow, iTotalRows, sFilePath, sSectionName, owb.fileFormat
    iCount = iCount + 1

    ' Exit
    Exit Do
End If
Loop

'Turn On Screen Updating  Events
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.EnableEvents = True

       MsgBox Str(iCount) + " documents saved in " + sFilePath


End Sub

Public Sub DeleteRows(targetSheet As Worksheet, RowFrom As Long, RowTo As Long)

    Dim rngRange As Range
Set rngRange = Range(targetSheet.Cells(RowFrom, 1), targetSheet.Cells(RowTo, 1)).EntireRow
rngRange.Select
rngRange.Delete

End Sub


Public Sub CopySheet(osh As Worksheet, iFirstRow As Long, iStartRow As Long, iStopRow As Long, iTotalRows As Long, sFilePath As String, sSectionName As String, fileFormat As XlFileFormat)
 Dim ash As Worksheet ' Copied sheet
 Dim awb As Workbook ' New workbook

 ' Copy book
 osh.Copy
 Set ash = Application.ActiveSheet

 ' Delete Rows after section
 If iTotalRows > iStopRow Then
     DeleteRows ash, iStopRow + 1, iTotalRows
 End If

 ' Delete Rows before section
 If iStartRow > iFirstRow Then
     DeleteRows ash, iFirstRow, iStartRow - 1
 End If

 ' Select left-topmost cell
 ash.Cells(1, 1).Select

 ' Clean up a few characters to prevent invalid filename
 sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, "/", " ")
 sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, "\", " ")
 sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, ":", " ")
 sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, "=", " ")
 sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, "*", " ")
 sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, ".", " ")
 sSectionName = Replace(sSectionName, "?", " ")

 ' Save in same format as original workbook
 ash.SaveAs sFilePath + "\Split\" + sSectionName, fileFormat

 ' Close
 Set awb = ash.Parent
 awb.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Hint: look at the additional parameters to the `SaveAs()` method of the workbook object.

Comment: Password protection on Excel files should be considered a minor inconvenience at best. It is trivial to remove/bypass such password protection (especially Excel 2007). See erikxiv’s answer below. I cannot stress the insecurity of this plan enough.

Answer (score 1):

> I need these files to be password protected so when I email them out to clients I feel that they are being transmitted securely.

Password protecting excel files should not be considered secure. There are multiple options online for cracking these type of documents, and even newer versions of excel still have security vulnerabilities. If the files contain sensitive data you should consider some other kind of encryption such as [PGP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy).